# Linux LiveCD with Xen DomU support?

Tags: linux, xen, live-cd

Can someone recommend a Linux LiveCD which can start as Xen DomU (paravirtualized, no HVM)?

Comment: there is xenoppix but ive never tried it http://unit.aist.go.jp/itri/knoppix/xen/index-en.html Usually I quickly reconfig the domU for hvm and boot the distro rescue image

Answer (score -1):

I thought paravirtualization was merged into the kernel in 2.6.23.  So any LiveCD based on a 2.6.23 kernel or newer should run as a DomU natively.

note:  I haven't tried this so I can't confirm that this will work.

Comment: Having paravirtualization in the kernel source tree doesn't mean it's enabled at compile time in distros. Generally it is not.